# why I can't retag a question?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits

Why I can't retag a question? I know that there is no more a separated retag link but yesterday I press edit on a question and just did a retag. But now I can't do just a retag and it says:

> You should make change at least 6 characters.

My reputation is 730 on Stack Overflow. The question is [How do you push HTML into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848869/how-do-you-push-html-into-an-array) I was trying to add [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui).

[image]

Comment: You probably have added at least a character in title or body section while re-tagging a question. Can you show the screen shot? And try it once again.

Comment: FYI, I just managed to edit (remove) a tag on your question ok, with no changes to content.

Comment: no ------------

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - He is talking about suggested edit.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - first whats FYI means. second I know I meant in stackoverflow not in meta I will out extra information on question.

Comment: I just suggested it back in (community rejected by hims056's edit, but it stuck)

Comment: @imsiso [FYI](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/FYI)

Comment: question updated now please help me.

Comment: @hims056: Oops, missed that bit.

Comment: @imsiso Have you retried just to make 100% sure there were no other edits. If so; screen shot?

Comment: @imsiso - Try to retag it once again. And if you get the error please update this question with screen shot.

Comment: what is screen shot?

Comment: @imsiso - See [what is screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot). Also [How to take a screenshot](http://www.take-a-screenshot.org/)

Comment: yes I tried again and that happened again.

Comment: oh my I knew that, I thought its something new that in stackoverflow. I can also capture video.

Comment: I can confirm that this is happening, I just tried to add the tag to the linked question

Comment: Interesting, I just tried annother retag on a different stack overflow question and had no problem. It seems to be specific to just that question; http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2951211

Comment: The curious thing is that if I edit [the revision #2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18848869/2) and just add `jquery-ui` [the auto-summary](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18848869/revisions) says: ***deleted 2 characters in body;** edited tags*.

Comment: sorry everybody I'm here but my internet is really too slow that I can see every word loading.

Comment: thanks everybody - I don't know why but It finally fixed. But the reason was unclear to me.

Comment: @imsiso It was only ever on that one question so something probably got messed up somewhere, I guess if it doesn't happen again we all move on

Comment: @RichardTingle - Sorry my English is not so good what you mean than ` I guess if it doesn't happen again we all move on`?

Comment: O, as in; if it doesn't happen again we will never know why it happened. Which is a shame

Comment: oh no don't talk about it like that, thank you, you did what you could and that's not your fault maybe it was a bug in Stack Overflow. thanks again.